# Web service & client in Java (Using Eclipse Apache Axis 2 Bottom Up Service) - certain codes throw exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I'm making my own web service [using this guide](http://www.windowstechupdates.com/how-to-develop-a-web-service-and-client-in-java-using-eclipse-apache-axis-2-bottom-up-sevice/), which is based on a zip code (received from the client) returns an object containing the temperature, city, googlemaps link and a `.wav` weather report as an `byte[]`. My web service actually uses another web service to obtain the data added it as it's done [here](http://www.texantek.com/forums/java/6147-creating-a-weather-webservice-client). But what my web service actually does is, that it generates the google maps URL and the sound file based on the data.

The web service successfully adds the city and temperature to the returning object (the client gets the data), but I run into problems when my web service tries to make the bytes array for the sound file.

First of all, I've additionally created a new class, which is in the same project and has the same code as the web service class, except that it also has a main function, so I can run it offline to see if the code works. I use it to test the code which does not work on the web service. To be exact, this code works perfectly fine on it's own:

```
public class Sound {

  public static byte[] getSound (String text) throws IOException {
    Voice voice;

    VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    voice = voiceManager.getVoice("kevin");
    FreeTTS freeTTS = new FreeTTS(voice);
    freeTTS.setAudioFile("recording.wav");
    freeTTS.startup();
    voice.allocate();      
    voice.speak(text);
    voice.deallocate();
    freeTTS.shutdown();

    File f = new File("recording.wav");

    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
      System.out.println("it exists");
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("recording.wav"));

    int read;
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
      out.write(buff, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();

    return audioBytes;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = Sound.getSound("Some text");
    System.out.println(data);
  }
}
```

But when the web service runs this code, exceptions occur.
Firstly, implying the recording.wav is already there (generated with the testing class above) and I'm not generating a new .wav, which is I am trying to make a byte[] from the recording.wav. In the test class, it says "recording.wav" exists, while when the running web service checks if the file exists, I get a null pointer exception, even though the webservice and the test class are in the same project/folder.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: recording.wav (The system cannot find the file specified)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Secondly, if i try to generate the sound file on the running web service an exception is thrown for this: `VoiceManager.getInstance();`

Client's side stack trace (copied only the first lines):

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com/sun/speech/freetts/VoiceManager
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

Web Services' side:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
```

I've tried redeploying the web service and client, nothing changed.Now, why is it that these errors occur when running as a web service, while they work perfectly fine running offline?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the FileNotFoundException you should check what your current working directory is because it most likely differs between your source and test directories.

Alternatively, you could use Java's [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to load the file. The [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) works by searching from the project directory regardless of the current working directory. So ...

```
URL url = Sound.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/path/to/recording.wav");
File f = new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: Interesting, I checked the path to the recording, which is: C:\Users\Me\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebSerice1337\WEB-INF\classes\recording.wav, let's see if i can make something of this information.

Comment: If i do the same with the test class, the recording is in a different folder:C:\Users\Me\workspace\WebSerice1337\build\classes\recording.wav

Comment: Thanks to this I'm using the url to read the sound file, so that is good. I'm guessing that when I'm using the VoiceManager, some libraries can't be accessed for similar reasons, which I'm not yet sure how to work around.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pretty sure I found my answer. The web service uses a different path than normal classes in the project. About the `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`, the web service also doesn't use the same `lib` folder as other calsses, I had to copy all my `.jar` files into the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder.